# Droid Incredible - Gmail Push - Can I add my hosted Email address to Gmail on my Droid?

Tags: email, gmail, htc-droid-incredible

I have an Adroid phone and want to set it up to sync with my business email account.  My account is hosted on my own domain, but we use email "provided by gmail" (gmail interface, connected to my domain).

Question: can I just add this as a normal gmail account on my Droid?  I tried this and my username and password don't work (which makes sense, b/c I don't have a real gmail/google account).
Or, do I need to add it as a generic POP or IMAP account?  If so, will push still work?

Answer (score 2):

When you add your email account through the Gmail app (Menu → Accounts → Add account), you'll usually need to use your full email address for the "username", rather than just your internal username.

In addition, if your company uses single sign-on for Google Apps (that is, if the login page for your business Gmail is **not** on google.com and doesn't look like the Gmail login page), you may need to set up a separate password for accessing Gmail from a non-web interface.  For this you'll need to talk to your IT department.

Comment: @crosstalk The interesting thing is, with the Gmail app in iOS I'm able to access both my company email (powered by Gmail) as well as my personal Gmail account. My company uses Single Sign-on. With the Gmail app in Android 4.0 I'm not able to setup my company email account at all. Really frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Google apps has [special setup (expand the "hidden" section for Android)](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=114408) -- not hard at all, though. I've set it up in more than one app as I try them out:

> To configure the 'Email' app on an
>   Android device for access to Google
>   Apps email, just follow the steps
>   below:
>
> 1. Enable IMAP in your Mail settings.
> 2. On your phone, press < Home >, then open the Email application.
> 3. On the 'Your accounts' page, select Next to get started with setup.
> 4. Enter your full Google Apps email address and password, then
>      select Next.
> 5. Select IMAP account and then select Next.
>
>    On the 'Incoming server settings' page, some fields may be
>      pre-populated. Make sure to change the
>      following:
> 6. For 'Username,' enter your full Google Apps email address
> 7. For 'IMAP server,' enter 'imap.gmail.com'
> 8. For 'Port,' enter '993'
> 9. For 'Security type,' select 'SSL (always)''
>
>    1. Select Next.
>
>       On the 'Outgoing server settings' page, some fields may be
>         pre-populated. Make sure to change the
>         following:
>    2. For 'SMTP server' enter 'smtp.gmail.com'
>    3. For 'Port,' enter '465'
>    4. For 'Security type,' select 'SSL (always)''
>    5. Select Next and continue through the setup options.

Comment: I can verify that this works with my two domains hosted on Google Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the Gmail app, then hit menu and click "Accounts". Try to add your account this way. If that doesn't work then you will need to use the Mail app and add the account as pop or imap.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add your business email (and calendar) as an additional Google account (I have with mine) - obviously making sure you enter your full email address including your company domain. If this is not working then speak to your domain admin in case they have locked down mobile access somehow :o/